# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. found error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Can anyone pls help me out with this problem?

```js
const Users = ({ users, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={users.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You try use `users` which = `undefined`

Comment: In TS you can add users?.map

Comment: @Isa [Optional chaining](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-OptionalExpression) is available in ES10, so it can be used across all JS-based programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [conditional operator `&&`](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) on before map

```
const Users = ({ users, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users && users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the map, you should use **user** not **users** so the code will be

```
{ users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
))}

Because, you are passing user as a argument for callback function not users.
```